# Crashes with completion handler in GameViewController

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Want to preload textureAtlases before game starts, so I decided to put scene starter code into completion handler, but for some reason app crashes. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gpuAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "GP")
        let ppAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "PP")

        SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([gpuAtlas, ppAtlas]) {

            if let view = self.view as? SKView {

                let scene = GameScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)


                view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                view.showsFPS = true
                view.showsNodeCount = true
            }
        } 
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

If I remove preload texture atlas method everything will work as usual, but I want preload textures to have a change to get rid of first keyframe freeze because of loading textures in cache.

**Error:**

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**Update:
It crashes on GameScene.swift file in method didSimulatePhysics.**

What I do wrong guys?

Comment: `if let view = self.view as! SKView?` looks strange. Shouldn't that be `if let view = self.view as? SKView`

Comment: @Gerriet changed but still the same.

Comment: Except of starting a game on a background thread, which is wrong, we can't tell what else you are doing wrong without a relevant code ;)

Comment: @Gerriet,  the default setup does that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (use `main thread` for manipulation with view and `weak self`):

```
SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([gpuAtlas, ppAtlas]) { [weak self] in
    guard let gameView = self?.view as? SKView else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let scene = GameScene(size: gameView.bounds.size)
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        // Present the scene
        gameView.presentScene(scene)
        gameView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        gameView.showsFPS = true
        gameView.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

Did you check if `scene` is optional? If so:

```
guard let scene = GameScene(size: gameView.bounds.size) else { return }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the provided code. All UI manipulation should be done on main thread. The completion handler of `preloadTextureAtlases` is executed on a background thread, so explicit grabbing of main thread is required.

Comment: Indeed, it is crashing because execution is being switched back to the main thread at some point before the completion handler is done, so you end up in some 1/2 finished state, causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
let gpuAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "GP")
let ppAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "PP")
SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([GP, PP]) {}
```

should not compile - the variables are named gpuAtlas and ppAtlas and not GP and PP.

Comment: Changed but still crashes on didSimulatePhysics

Comment: That's another problem.

Comment: Right, but as I said if I delete this preload atlas methods everything will work fine.